# htaccess: доступ к папке и файлам, если она существует

Tags: .htaccess, файлы

День добрый, столкнулся с проблемой что не могу в корне получить доступ к папке `jscript`
При обращении на прямую к папке `jscript` она отдает 404, как-будто это контроллер.
в `.htaccess` сайта написано следующее:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop.php?$1 [L]
```

Задача стояла следующая если человек обращается "`domain.com/shop`" его перекидывало в магазин где `URI` задан "`shop`", теперь он эту папку `jscript` принимает как `URI` для магазина
`FrameWork: CodeIgniter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Задача стояла следующая если человек
> обращается "domain.com/shop" его
> перекидывало в магазин где URI задан
> "shop", теперь он эту папку jscript
> принимает как URI для магазина
> FrameWork: CodeIgniter.

```
RewriteRule ^shop$ /shop.php [R=301,L]
```

Может вам нужно не чтобы "перекидывало", а немного другое? По идее понимаю так: если человек обращается по адресу: `domain.ru/shop,` то действует правила, которые запрос передают файлу `shop.php`, а при других обращениях - нет.

Comment: Так вот именно что вместо "shop" могло быть любое слово ;) кроме заданных папок в каталоге сайта. например css jscript images.

Comment: @Quiss

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css(.*)$
RewriteRule ^shop(.*) shop.php?$1 [L]

Что-то не хочет никак апач по другому работать. хмм.

Comment: Спасибо за предложенные варианты, на работе буду гляну может что и получиться =)

Comment: Переписал скрипты своего Tiny MCE и все заработало) перенес в корень. Спасибо все-равно, Вариант lampa оказался самым наилучшим.

Answer (score 3):

Пропишите перед RewriteBase:

```
RewriteRule ^jscript/(.*)$ jscript/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо.